# SMS Website , Barred or Not Barred Php

Tags: php, mysql, html

Im starting a sms website and im nearly complete - just one feature i need to add into it and im a but stuck,

Ive got a form that they fill out with their name , number and message and then they click send , that gets sent to another form to proceed with the validation of the message etc,

What i need is to be able to crosslist the number field against a known database list of blacklisted numbers that dont want messages sent to their phone.

This is the checking code at the moment: so if you imagine at the moment there is a button called send and a button called check number.

When you click check number it will either find the number or not , I know its strange having 2 numbers but its the way its built at the moment.

NOW , instead of it saying number not found id like it to enable the send button , I know how to disable it via disabled="disabled" but i dont know how to automate it , Id like the button greyed out when users go to the form , then when this checks the numbers id like it to ungrey the button if the number isnt in the list.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx_members","xxxx");
if(!$con)
{
die("could not connect:".mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("xxx_number",$con);
$mobile = $_GET['c'];
$count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from mobileCheck where number = '".$number."'"));

if($count > 0) {
echo "Number found">";

}else{
echo "Number Not Found">";
}

?>
```

Any help on this would be appreciated , its starting to drive me up the wall

Thanks

Comment: You will need ajax to do this.

Comment: Hmm I tried ajax but i couldnt seem to get it working , hence why i swapped to this , 

if(response == 1){
 $('#username').css('border', '3px #C33 solid'); 
 $('#tick').hide();
 $('#cross').fadeIn();
 $('#continueButton').attr("disabled", true);
 }else{
 $('#username').css('border', '3px #090 solid');
 $('#cross').hide();
 $('#tick').fadeIn();
      }

that was part of my response on the check but it never seemed to disable the button

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). If you are planning to operate a SMS service with no traffic/cost limit, you should definitely have an understanding of basic security  before going online.

Comment: Yes, you need to look into parameterized queries. And although it's convenient to enable and disable a button on your page, that won't stop someone who knows what they're doing from submitting your form anyways. Make sure you validate the number again before actually sending the message.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to correct your php code that you listed:

```
if($count > 0) {
echo "1";

}else{
echo "0";
}
```

Now you need to make and ajax call to the above file when the first button is clicked using JS and collect back the server response, i.e, either 1 or 0. Now you need to do a client side checking of the server response and enable the button dynamically using javascript it the server echoed 1.

Answer (score 0):

number_check.php

```
 <?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","xxx_members","xxxx");
    if(!$con)
      die("could not connect:".mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("xxx_number",$con);
    $number = $_POST['number'];
    $count = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("select * from mobileCheck where number = '".$number."'"));

    if($count > 0) 
    {
    echo 1;
    }else{
    echo 0;
    }

    ?>
```

html:

```
<input type="text" id="number" value="" />
<input type="button" id="btn_send" value="Send SMS" disabled />
```

javascript - jQuery:

```
$.post("number_check.php", { number: $('#number').value},
   function(data) {
     if (data == '1')
       $('#btn_send').disabled = false;
     else
       $('#btn_send').disabled = true;
   });
```

I'm sorry but I didn't test the solution, but I think this is your answer. You will of course need to test the number with the db on post, because enabling the button is simple and could be a possible flaw, so you cannot rely on disabling the button, it is only for ergonomic purposes.